# Do t-shirts and other SO swag still have the old logo?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone, logo

As a part of the 10 million questions milestone, SO is sending swag (t-shirts, mugs, ...) to some of its users. Has the logo on this swag been updated or is it still the old one?

Since we reached the milestone before the logo was updated, I'm guessing the swag will come with the old logo, but I wanted to have some confirmation.

For reference, here is the old logo:

[image]

And here is the new one:

[image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

All of the swag will still have the old logo on it. We won't get new swag with the new logo until the current stock is used up. Think of it as vintage.

For clarification, this is the logo that will be on your swag:

[image]

This is not the *original* logo, but a slightly less curvy version of the original which debuted about a couple years ago (that's a complete guess, I have no idea what the exact date was).

([SVG source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/0/02/20150916153753!Stack_Overflow_logo.svg))

Comment: "First edition."

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Technically *not* first edition, because the logo has changed once before. It got less curvy. First edition stuff is pretty cool, though. I have a few.

Comment: @animuson could you add the pic of old and new logos?

Comment: @AvinashRaj [New](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OoWyF.png). [Old](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ09E.png).

Comment: @NathanOsman and what about the first edition one that animuson talked about?

Comment: @Aequitas His "Old" link is actually the original "first edition" logo. [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/0/02/20150916153753!Stack_Overflow_logo.svg) is what the second in-between logo looked like, which is the logo that will be on the current swag. Slightly less curvy than the original.

Comment: Does this mean we can get more for them when we sell them on eBay? :)

Comment: Looking at how the logos have evolved, it won't be long before there is no overflow. :)

Comment: So *that's* why a bunch of swag is being given away...

Comment: I am happy to volunteer to help use up one T-shirt of the current stock :)

Comment: @rybo111 Once all the bars disappear, they'll start appearing out the bottom of the tray and we will rebrand to Stack Underflow.

Comment: The liberal use of 'swag' is bothersome

Comment: @animuson I edited your answer in order to upload the image on imgur. (I don't know if Wikimedia is a reliable image host)

Comment: My T-Shirt hasn't updated itself

Comment: @Amicable That's because you haven't connected it to the Internet yet.

Answer (score 62):

Feel free to make your own shirt with the old-school logo:

[image]

The new old logo:

[image]

Or with the logo from 2050 (since the logo lost 1 bar in 7 years, it will take about 35 years to lose 5 bars):

[image]

Bonus: the logo which will appear after the merge of Stack Overflow and Google+:

[image]

Comment: [Joke #605](https://xkcd.com/605/) is appropriate here.

Comment: Is it adequate to say that, in 2050, the company will be renamed to stack flow ?

Comment: But what if bar decay is exponential?  We don't have enough data to say otherwise.  6 to 5 bars in 7 years is a half-life of 26.612 years.

Comment: +1 Was this based on my comment? :)

Comment: @JeffNoel By 2057 the company will be renamed to Empty Stack, Inc.

Comment: @rybo111 yes it inspired me to make these absurd images, and thanks for the edit!

Comment: And by 2064 company will be named stack underflow or index out of bounds

Comment: [Here's another "future" version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4569) from CodeGolf SE.

Comment: I vote for "index out of bounds"